# Rollover effect (not on image) in list item

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating a menu in my website which is written something this:
**HTML code**

```
<ul id="menu">
<li><a href="index.aspx">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="about.aspx">About</a></li>
<li><a href="sample.aspx">Sample</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS code**

```
ul#menu li a:link,ul#menu li a:visited {color:#333333;text-decoration:none;}
ul#menu li a:hover,ul#manu li a:active {color:#a61607;text-decoration:none;}
```

On the hover of each of the list items, I want show an image on the hover (the images are such that it appears at the boundaries of the text of each list item). This means that the image that is appearing does not have to appear over the text and does not have to replace. It just displaces on the side of the text and disappears when the hover is over.
For each of the list items, there is a separate image assciated for rollover, and has to disappear on the mouse is moved away from the list item text. I am not sure how to get the above effect and all the links that I have followed are guides to chnage the image on rollover. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you clarify where the image is?

Comment: @HopeIHelped: Editted the question and added detail about this

Answer (score 1):

You add an image inside the list items after each one of your links. You set `display: none;` on the images and then you can reveal them on hover using `ul#menu li:hover img {display: inline-block}`

Demo: http://dabblet.com/gist/3151894

The HTML becomes simply:

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="index.aspx">Home</a><img src="imghome.png"></li>
    <li><a href="about.aspx">About</a><img src="imgabout.png"></li>
    <li><a href="sample.aspx">Sample</a><img src="imgsample.png"></li>
</ul>
```

In the CSS, I've only added:

```
#menu li img {
    width: 15px;
    display: none;
}
#menu li:hover img { display: inline-block; }
```

**EDIT**: Alternatively, the image can be displayed using

```
#menu a:hover + img { display: inline-block; }
```

Comment: Thanks! But can this hover to display be made somehow to work only on a:hover rather than using li:hover. My li has a large width and it doesn't look nice to get the rollover image before I am on the text.

Comment: Thanks again. That does have solve the problem but that leads me to ask another thing about how I can get this displayed image over the text itself. As in, the image (which is a png) should overlap with the <a> elements text. This picture makes it clear of what I am asking -> i.imgur.com/Yxlpv.png . I wanted to ask how do I get these images overlapping with the text where the text if the text of <a> elements?

Answer (score 0):

you can do this:

```
<ul id="menu">
<li><a id="firstLi" href="index.aspx">Home</a></li>
<li><a id="secondLi" href="about.aspx">About</a></li>
<li><a id="thirdLi" href="sample.aspx">Sample</a></li>
</ul>


a#firstLi:hover {background: url('images/image1.png')}
a#secondLi:hover {background: url('images/image2.png')}
a#thirdLi:hover {background: url('images/image3.png')}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the css:

```
ul#menu li a:link,ul#menu li a:visited {color:#333333;text-decoration:none;}
ul#menu li a:hover,ul#manu li a:active {color:#a61607;text-decoration:none;}
ul#menu li img {display: none;}
ul#menu li:hover img {display: inline-block;}​
```

I used the same image for all three links, googled a test image to use. Obviously you will use whatever image(s) you want.

```
<ul id="menu">
<li>
    <a href="index.aspx">
        Home
        <img src="http://icons.mysitemyway.com/wp-content/gallery/3d-glossy-green-orbs-icons-symbols-shapes/thumbs/thumbs_104626-3d-glossy-green-orb-icon-symbols-shapes-check-mark5-ps.png" />
    </a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="about.aspx">
        About
        <img src="http://icons.mysitemyway.com/wp-content/gallery/3d-glossy-green-orbs-icons-symbols-shapes/thumbs/thumbs_104626-3d-glossy-green-orb-icon-symbols-shapes-check-mark5-ps.png" />
    </a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="sample.aspx">
        Sample
        <img src="http://icons.mysitemyway.com/wp-content/gallery/3d-glossy-green-orbs-icons-symbols-shapes/thumbs/thumbs_104626-3d-glossy-green-orb-icon-symbols-shapes-check-mark5-ps.png" />
    </a>
</li>
```

​​​​​​​​​​​​

**Edits to respond to op's comment**

If you want the icon/image to appear when you rollover the anchor instead of the li. You would change the 4th css line to something like this:

```
ul#menu a:hover img {display: inline-block;}​
```

However, I don't know what additional CSS you have to size or position your elements. When I ran just this CSS and HTML in jsfiddle, I run into a "fluttering" issue. When hovering over the anchor, the image is showing but it re-positions all other elements and a sort of hover/non-hover occurs. If I add the following CSS rule that makes my anchors within the list/list items block elements, I have no problem.

```
ul#menu li a {display: block;}
```

Additionally, you could also set the height/width or the padding of the anchor or li element to adjust to the dimensions of your images.

Comment: Thanks! But can this hover to display be made somehow to work only on a:hover rather than using li:hover. My li has a large width and it doesn't look nice to get the rollover image before I am on the text.

Comment: Thanks again. That does have solve the problem but that leads me to ask another thing about how I can get this displayed image over the text itself. As in, the image (which is a png) should overlap with the <a> elements text. This picture makes it clear of what I am asking -> i.imgur.com/Yxlpv.png . I wanted to ask how do I get these images overlapping with the text where the text if the text of <a> elements?

Comment: Not exactly sure what that image is implying. Could you explain a little more? All you would need to do is to change the line that sets the a:hover img {display: inline-block;} to add some positioning in there. You would want to absolutely position the element and move it around with the top,left,right,bottom css properties. That means the element is absolutely positioned within it's parent element (the A). Then you can adjust the element within the container by moving it around using those position properties and assigning pixel values until the image is in the right location.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Q6CaM/

**HTML**

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="index.aspx">Home</a><img src="http://www.fmwconcepts.com/misc_tests/lena_label2.jpg" /></li>
<li><a href="about.aspx">About</a><img src="http://www.fmwconcepts.com/misc_tests/lena_label2.jpg" /></li>
<li><a href="sample.aspx">Sample</a><img src="http://www.fmwconcepts.com/misc_tests/lena_label2.jpg" /></li>
</ul>​
```

**CSS**

```
li{display:block; overflow:hidden;}
a{display:inline-block; float:left; margin:0 5px 0 0;}
img {display:none; position:absolute; }
li:hover img{display:inline-block;}
```